# Two Tkinter Questions

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to change the color of certain particular bits of text in the entry widget, or does it all have to be the same color?

Is it possible to change the Tk logo in the top right to a different image?

Comment: this looks like two queries in one question to me as opposed to two questions. I feel misled. I thought you'd found a way to put two questions on one url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, you cannot change the color of just a part of the text in an entry widget. If you need to do that you can use a Text widget.

From [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm), the best tkinter reference on the web:

> **When to use the Entry Widget**
>
> The entry widget is used to enter text strings. This widget allows the user to enter one line of text, in a single font.
>
> To enter multiple lines of text, use the Text widget.

The Text widget has this capability thanks to the Tag concept see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

2) Yes

```
 root = Tk()
 root.wm_iconbitmap('my_icon.ico')
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Bryan : Thanks for your edit. It males the answer easier to understand